# Why I have to select 2 times (different photo) for displaying image in firebase storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

When I click uploading images first time it shows loading affect but show nothing even background image for uploading and then I have to upload different image for displaying image before submitting to go to Newfeed-page that show my account.So Iam not sure that because my code or firebase service that I have to config some rule. Thanks for helping me

```
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import {
  ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL, getStorage
} from "firebase/storage";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Avatar = styled.div`
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
cursor: pointer;
`;

function Photo() {
  const [cookies] = useCookies(["userName"]);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("./images/UploadPic.svg");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      setImage(e.target.files[0]);
      const storage = getStorage();
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${cookies.userName}`);
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        () => {
          setUrl("./loading.gif");
        },
        (error) => {
          switch (error.code) {
            case "storage/unauthorized":
              console.log("storage is unauthorized");
              break;
            case "storage/canceled":
              console.log("storage is canceled");
              break;
            case "storage/unknown":
              console.log("storage is unknown");
              break;
            default:
              console.log("sorry it is not about storage");
          }
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(storageRef).then((url) => {
            setUrl(url);
          });
        },
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
      <label htmlFor="file-input">
        <Avatar style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${url})` }} />
      </label>
      <input id="file-input" type="file"  accept="image/*" onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Photo;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="file-input" type="file"  accept="image/*" onChange={handleChange} />
```

hey please try changing above line to below

```
<input id="file-input" type="file"  accept="image/*" onChange={() => handleChange()} />
```

not sure though worth trying

Comment: it shows error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')" but I add e to onChange={() => handleChange()} to become onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} then I have to select 2 different photo again lololol so weird